# Linq To Update One Complete Row

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

So I would like to update/replace one complete row with the data I have.
Instead of doing
entityA.Name = entityB.Name

I would like to say something like entityA = entityB, where entitiyB is same as entityA but has new values.

Please let me know.

Thanks..

Comment: What should we let you know?

Comment: So I am trying to do this entityA = entityB, but that is not working for me. I am also doing db.SaveChanges(), but my database is not showing the new values?

Comment: can you just add `entityB` and remove `entityA` ?

Answer (score 0):

simply doing `entity1 = entity2` would change the entity1 reference and hence the context wont track the new reference ay more. Thus the changd value wont be updated.

you should be using an object mapper for that. i personally use GLUE that can be installed using command `Install-Package Glue` on the package manager console
There are others too like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

if you go with glue then just make a mapping like

```
var mapping = new Mapping<entity1, entity2>();
mapping.AutoRelateEqualNames();
//or define a mapping using .Relate()
//then call map
mapping.Map(entity1)//this will return entity2
or if you already have an object tracked by a context class call
entity2 = mapping.Map(entity1, entity2);
```

Comment: I am using Automapper now, but even this is not updating my database. This is my code - 
        RecordtoUpdate = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(datafromForm, RecordtoUpdate )
        dbContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: I am using Automapper now, but even this is not updating my database. This is my code - RecordtoUpdate = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(datafromForm, RecordtoUpdate ) dbContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: see this. thought i dont use automapper i think this will solve your problem https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions

Comment: for glue though this is the link you must be looking at http://glue.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Strict%20and%20Automagical%20Modes&referringTitle=Home